# Why is my new active duplicate rule not taking precedence over an older and now deacivated duplicate rule?

Tags: contact, duplicate-management, merge, duplicate-matching-rule

I'm attempting to use Contact merge app with the non-profit success pack, however upon using contact merge, duplicate contacts appear with the duplicate rule ID being "**Name and DOB check**". This duplicate rule has been deactivated yet still seems to be checked with contact merge. A newer duplicate rule "**Is Name Matching?**" has been created along with its corresponding matching rule with both being active, however contacts that should be appearing as duplicate under "**Is Name Matching?**" are not appearing in duplicate merge. Does deactivating a matching and duplicate rule not affect its use in Contact Merge? Or is there possibly some other issue present here? If so how can i ensure Contact Merge uses the newer Duplicate Rule?